# Multipy matrix by its transpose in constant memory

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have an MxN matrix **X**, where M is manageable, but N is very large. The matrix is Wikipedia  in term-document corpus format, to give you some context. I need to compute:

```
X.dot(X.T)
```

I know that the result (dimensions MxM) will fit into memory, but the matrix X will not.

How do I best compute the product, iterating over the columns of X batch wise? I have the corpus saved as a file, and I'm able to iterate over each document (i.e. columns of X) one by one. Is there a way to iteratively build X * X.T?

I happen to work with Numpy for this, but really any description of an algorithm would be great.

Comment: what happens if `X = np.memmap(..)`?

Comment: did you try working with sparse matrix? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: The comments `M is manageable, but N is very large`, and `NxN) will fit into memory, but ...  X will not` dont seem to make sense

Comment: True, I meant (MxM), which would be correct. Edited the question. As for sparse matrices, that's actually what I'm using right now, but it doesn't allow for large enough Ns. I'll look into memmapping!

Comment: @pdowling you need at least twice the size of memory of `X`, than you can do `Y = np.empty_like(X); np.dot(X, X.T, out=Y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the definition of matrix product:

```
Y = np.zeros((M, M), dtype=float)
for j in xrange(N):
    Y += X[:,np.newaxis,j] * X.T[j,np.newaxis,:]
```

using larger blocks can improve performance:

```
block_size = 256
Y = np.zeros((M, M), dtype=float)
for j in xrange(0, N, block_size):
    Xb = X[:,j:(j+block_size)]
    Y += Xb.dot(Xb.T)
```

**EDIT**: forgot np.newaxis from the first example

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks a lot. I kind of expected there to be more of a trick to it!